# Google Mock: passing pointer to mock object, but method call is still calling real method

Tags: c++, googlemock

i have this simple code

```
struct SimpleStruct {
    int add(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
};

class SimpleClass {
public:
    int SimpleMethod(SimpleStruct* simpleStruct, int a, int b) {
        return simpleStruct->add(a, b);
    }
};
```

Now I would like to test the `SimpleMethod` and mock the `SimpleStruct` like this:

```
struct MockSimpleStruct : public SimpleStruct {
    MOCK_METHOD(int, add, (int, int), (const));
};


TEST(Test_Calculation, simpleStruct) {
    MockSimpleStruct mockSimpleStruct;

    EXPECT_CALL(mockSimpleStruct, add(_,_)).Times(2).WillOnce(DoAll(Return(7))).WillOnce(DoAll(Return(7)));
    EXPECT_EQ(7, mockSimpleStruct.add(2, 3)); // working fine

    SimpleClass simpleClass;
    int result = simpleClass.SimpleMethod(&mockSimpleStruct, 2, 3); // not working: inside SimpleMethod the real add method is called

    EXPECT_EQ(7, result); // fails
}
```

How can I assure that the mocked method is being used?

My question is related to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063013/gmock-passing-a-mocked-object-into-another-and-calling-a-stubed-method-is-still), but I cannot change the use of SimpleStruct in the signature of SimpleMethod, because in my case my signature is defined through the jni.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmock can mock only `virtual` functions, so in order for it to work `add()` should be declared virtual. But it only necessary for it to be virtual for unit testing, so you can do something like:

```
#ifdef UNDER_TEST
#define TEST_VIRTUAL virtual
#else
#define TEST_VIRTUAL
#endif

struct SimpleStruct {
    TEST_VIRTUAL int add(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
};
```

Just make sure that tested code doesn't depend from fact that SimpleStruct is POD.